# Difficulty understanding 'useState' in 'react-redux'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

what is the purpose of `useState`?

what is it doing ? what is the value '0'?

what does `useState` function returns ?

can we write anything in place of `currentId` and `setCurrentId`?

i am from java language . this whole syntax looks very weird . generally we write like this => `int a = sum(b,c);` in java but in this case we have square brackets with two variables in it . what kind of thing is this ?

```
const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0);
```

Comment: This looks like at least two questions at once - one about `useState` semantics, which can be answered by quoting the React documentation and providing the simple example, and another about JavaScript syntax, which should be answered either by describing the syntax or by linking to the duplicate, if it exists. Voting to close for now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Redux. `useState` is a *Hook*. See: [*Using the State Hook*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). I am voting to close this question since it can be resolved by a simple reference to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState is not from `react-redux`, but React itself, it's called a hook

What you are doing is you are initializing a value, called `currentId` with the value 0.
`setCurrentId` is the function that you would use to update the state.
Yes you can write anything you want instead of those, for example

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
if(condition) setNumber(1)
```